# Android how to get UTC Timezone offset even of negative timezone

Tags: java, android

Hi I am trying to send the UTC offset towards my server. So I am converting the device time zone into utc offset using following code

```
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();

    Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(tz);

    int offsetInMillis = tz.getOffset(cal.getTimeInMillis());

    String offset = String.format("%02d:%02d", Math.abs(offsetInMillis / 3600000), Math.abs((offsetInMillis / 60000) % 60));


    Log.d("UTC_Offset",offset);
```

Now i know as I am using the Math.abs it is not giving me the minus values but I am really dumb to know that how could I get the offset of those timezone who are in negative such as Tijuana which is GMT-07:00

**Note:** I may be wrong about the offset thing in UTC but this solution I found on SO. Please let me know if there is any solution or also correct me if I am wrong in idea and its that UTC could not be in negative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SimpleDateFormat` to format it for you:

```
String offset = new SimpleDateFormat("Z").format(new Date());
offset = offset.substring(0, 3) + ":" + offset.substring(3);
```

↓↓↓↓↓   IGNORE REST OF ANSWER IF IT IS CONFUSING   ↓↓↓↓↓

Results when applying to all TimeZones in the Java VM:

```
-12:00
-11:00
-10:00
-09:30
-09:00
-08:00
-07:00
-06:00
-05:00
-04:00
-03:00
-02:30
-02:00
-01:00
+00:00
+01:00
+02:00
+03:00
+04:00
+04:30
+05:00
+05:30
+05:45
+06:00
+06:30
+07:00
+08:00
+08:45
+09:00
+09:30
+10:00
+10:30
+11:00
+12:00
+12:45
+13:00
+14:00
```

Java 8 code to print the above:

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("Z");
ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds().stream()
    .map(z -> ZoneId.of(z).getRules().getOffset(now))
    .distinct()
    .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
    .forEach(z -> {
        fmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(z));
        String offset = fmt.format(Date.from(now));
        offset = offset.substring(0, 3) + ":" + offset.substring(3);
        System.out.println(offset);
    });
```

Comment: I am not using java 8, can you send me with out this lamda

Comment: and are these UTC outcomes those you printed out

Comment: @A.s.ALI The 2 lines of code at the top works on Android. The rest is just output and code to show what the result of those 2 lines of code can be. --- Yes, *"code to print the above"* means that "these UTC outcomes are those I printed out". That code is not meant for Android, which is why I said *"Java 8"*.

Comment: So U mean using  this will be enough for my problem 

String offset = new SimpleDateFormat("Z").format(new Date());
offset = offset.substring(0, 3) + ":" + offset.substring(3);

Comment: @A.s.ALI That is what the answer says, yes. "Use this" then 2 lines of code. I can delete the rest if it really confuses you that much.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

> how could I get the offset of those timezone who are in negative such as Tijuana which is GMT-07:00

```
ZoneId.of( "America/Tijuana" ).getRules().getOffset( Instant.now() ).getTotalSeconds()
```

> -25200

- No need to do the math yourself. We have classes for this: [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html).
- For older Java before Java 8, use the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) library.

  - For older Android, see the [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project.
- Avoid `Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, and `TimeZone` legacy classes.

Example:

```
org.threeten.bp.ZoneId
.systemDefault()
.getRules()
.getOffset​(
    Instant.now()
)
.toString()
```

To get total seconds of that offset, call `ZoneOffset::getTotalSeconds`.

## *java.time*

The modern approach uses the modern *java.time* classes. You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by *java.time*.

Get the [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) of the computer’s [current default](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html#systemDefault()) [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;
ZoneRules rules = z.getRules() ;
ZoneOffset offset = rules.getOffset( Instant.now() ) ;
```

Notice that we passed a moment, represented as `Instant` object (a moment as seen in UTC). Politicians frequently change the offset used by the zone(s) of their jurisdiction. So the offset of your zone is likely to change over time. So you must specify a moment to ask for the offset that was in effect at that point in time.

Generate text representing that offset, using standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```
String output = offset.toString() ;
```

> -07:00

When receiving such text, you can parse as a `ZoneOffset` object.

```
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.parse( "-07:00" ) ;
```

You asked:

> that UTC could not be in negative

An negative offset means a place whose clocks run *behind* UTC. Generally, this means west (left) of the prime meridian, such as the Americas.

A positive offset means a place whose clocks run *ahead* of UTC. Generally, this means east (right) of the prime meridian, such as Europe, Africa, Asia.

Well, this is the commonly used meaning of positive & negative offsets, defined in the ISO 8601 standard. Some protocols and industries may use the opposite meaning. Always understand the intention of any data source you may be using.

> how could I get the offset of those timezone who are in negative such as Tijuana which is GMT-07:00

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Tijuana" ) ;
ZoneRules rules = z.getRules() ;
ZoneOffset offset = rules.getOffset( Instant.now() ) ;
String output = offset.toString() ;

System.out.println( output ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/jcnyIt).

> -07:00

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).